# How to grab a specific text value from a big text or html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, regex

I would want to get only the path value form the below text/html.  Actually it contains 10k lines, it would be very difficult to manually take the all path values. Is this possible to get the only path values through regex or through excel or any other possible way?

I would want to grab and take all the path value alone from the href attribute

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>account</th>
         <th>size</th>
         <th>nodes</th>
         <th>props</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href=" /reports/?path=/root/en/products-services/course-products">course-products</a></td>
         <td class="number">955MB</td>
         <td class="number">80607</td>
         <td class="number">549393</td>
         <td width="100%">
            <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border-width:1;width:58%" class="bar"></td>
                     <td style="border: none; width:42%"><b>58%</b></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="/reports/?path=/root/products-services/silverthorn-7e-info">silverthorn-7e-info</a></td>
         <td class="number">83.5MB</td>
         <td class="number">149</td>
         <td class="number">778</td>
         <td width="100%">
            <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border-width:1;width:5%" class="bar"></td>
                     <td style="border: none; width:95%"><b>5%</b></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="/reports/?path =/root/products-services/sanders-2e-info">sanders-2e-info</a></td>
         <td class="number">45.5MB</td>
         <td class="number">9609</td>
         <td class="number">67184</td>
         <td width="100%">
            <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border-width:1;width:3%" class="bar"></td>
                     <td style="border: none; width:97%"><b>3%</b></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="/reports/?path=/root/products-services/davidson-10e-info">davidson-10e-info</a></td>
         <td class="number">39MB</td>
         <td class="number">53</td>
         <td class="number">288</td>
         <td width="100%">
            <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border-width:1;width:2%" class="bar"></td>
                     <td style="border: none; width:98%"><b>2%</b></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
```

Comment: You can do this by using javascript.

Comment: Hi, I provided a better approach and two different type of working solutions below. Just wondering any reason you decide to choose the other answer but not mine. Let me know Just so I can improve my answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, with `.each`, you can do something like that

```
$( "tr" ).each(function( index ) {
    let ahref = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    console.log(ahref);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either use `JavaScript` or `jQuery` both to achieve the results you are after.

**Using `jQuery` way**

You can use `$.each` along with `href` to get the `a` elements `hrefs` only from your table.

Also, to target the `a` only - We can use `jQuery` [Descendant Selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) like this below.

```
$("table tr > td > a").each(function(i, el) {
  console.log(el.href) //get a href only
});
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
$("table tr > td > a").each(function(i, el) {
  console.log(el.href) //get a href only
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>account</th>
      <th>size</th>
      <th>nodes</th>
      <th>props</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href=" /reports/?path=/root/en/products-services/course-products">course-products</a></td>
      <td class="number">955MB</td>
      <td class="number">80607</td>
      <td class="number">549393</td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-width:1;width:58%" class="bar"></td>
              <td style="border: none; width:42%"><b>58%</b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/reports/?path=/root/products-services/silverthorn-7e-info">silverthorn-7e-info</a></td>
      <td class="number">83.5MB</td>
      <td class="number">149</td>
      <td class="number">778</td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-width:1;width:5%" class="bar"></td>
              <td style="border: none; width:95%"><b>5%</b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/reports/?path =/root/products-services/sanders-2e-info">sanders-2e-info</a></td>
      <td class="number">45.5MB</td>
      <td class="number">9609</td>
      <td class="number">67184</td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-width:1;width:3%" class="bar"></td>
              <td style="border: none; width:97%"><b>3%</b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/reports/?path=/root/products-services/davidson-10e-info">davidson-10e-info</a></td>
      <td class="number">39MB</td>
      <td class="number">53</td>
      <td class="number">288</td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-width:1;width:2%" class="bar"></td>
              <td style="border: none; width:98%"><b>2%</b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Using only Pure `JavaScript` way**

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method along with `forEach` method to get the `href` as well from the `a`

```
const el = document.querySelectorAll('table tr > td > a')
el.forEach(function(el, i) {
  console.log(el.href) //get a href only
})
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
const el = document.querySelectorAll('table tr > td > a')
el.forEach(function(el, i) {
  console.log(el.href) //get a href only
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>account</th>
      <th>size</th>
      <th>nodes</th>
      <th>props</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href=" /reports/?path=/root/en/products-services/course-products">course-products</a></td>
      <td class="number">955MB</td>
      <td class="number">80607</td>
      <td class="number">549393</td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-width:1;width:58%" class="bar"></td>
              <td style="border: none; width:42%"><b>58%</b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/reports/?path=/root/products-services/silverthorn-7e-info">silverthorn-7e-info</a></td>
      <td class="number">83.5MB</td>
      <td class="number">149</td>
      <td class="number">778</td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-width:1;width:5%" class="bar"></td>
              <td style="border: none; width:95%"><b>5%</b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/reports/?path =/root/products-services/sanders-2e-info">sanders-2e-info</a></td>
      <td class="number">45.5MB</td>
      <td class="number">9609</td>
      <td class="number">67184</td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-width:1;width:3%" class="bar"></td>
              <td style="border: none; width:97%"><b>3%</b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/reports/?path=/root/products-services/davidson-10e-info">davidson-10e-info</a></td>
      <td class="number">39MB</td>
      <td class="number">53</td>
      <td class="number">288</td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table style="border: none;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-width:1;width:2%" class="bar"></td>
              <td style="border: none; width:98%"><b>2%</b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```